# Selenium only changes the first dropdown menu then ignores the rest - C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a unit test in selenium that modifies a series of dropdown menus to test if their options are loading correctly and work as intended.

At the moment the test is using FindElements and XPath to get all of the drop down menus and uses a foreach loop to select and modify each one.

When it runs, the first dropdown menu is changed, it continues on selecting the rest of them one at a time but it never changes the option.

I've tried adding explicit and implicit waits to see if it was just going too fast and skipping over them. That didn't solve it so I added a thread.sleep() to try and follow what its doing. Each menu is clicked on correctly, but the option is never changed for any of them except the first.

C#

```
public bool editMessages(IWebDriver driver, String option) 
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement selectOption;
    foreach (var selectBox in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("(//div[@class = 'col-4']//select)")))
    {
        selectBox.Click();
        selectOption = selectBox.FindElement(By.XPath($"//option[text() = '{option}']"));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        selectOption.Click();
    }
    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-4" ng-show="editMessagesMode" aria-hidden="false" style="">
  <span>
    <select class="selectbox ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required  ng- touched" name="messageSelect" ng-model="message.status" required="" ng-change="updateSelectedMessageValues(message.message_id, value)" style="height: 35px; width: 100%; float: left; margin-top: -11px; padding: 1px; color: rgb(0, 85, 165);" ng-options="c.value as ('MESSAGE_TYPE_' + c.value) | translate for c  in selectMessages" aria-invalid="false">
      <option disabled="" translate="SELECT" value="" class="">Select</option>
      <option label="In-Active" value="number:0">In-Active</option>
      <option label="Cups-On" value="number:1" selected="selected">Cups-On</option>
      <option label="Cups-Off" value="number:2">Cups-Off</option>
      <option label="Both" value="number:3">Both</option>
    </select>
  </span>
</div>
```

There's 5 of these identical dropdowns in total for now but this number fluctuates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem very likely is this line

```
selectOption = selectBox.FindElement(By.XPath($"//option[text() = '{option}']"));
```

You are starting the search for the new element from an existing one, `selectBox`. In order to do that with an XPath, you have to start the XPath with `.` so that line would change to

```
selectOption = selectBox.FindElement(By.XPath($".//option[text() = '{option}']"));
                                                ^
```

---

Also, there is a built in `SelectElement` class specifically designed to make working with SELECT elements easier. If we change the code over to use that, it becomes MUCH simpler.

```
public bool editMessages(IWebDriver driver, String option)
{
    foreach (IWebElement selectBox in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("(//div[@class = 'col-4']//select)")))
    {
        new SelectElement(selectBox).SelectByText(option);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I knew I overlooked something, thank you, that works flawlessly

Comment: @ChellCPlus I added some updated, simpler code using `SelectElement`. Please don't forget to upvote any answer that you found useful and accept an answer when you've found the one that works for you so the question isn't left unanswered.